# Change Color detailTextLabel tableView with Custom Cells swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've created custom `tableView` like this and I want to change `detailTextLabel` if row is selected.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        let selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell!.frame.size.width, cell!.frame.size.height))
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView

        let textHeader = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(45, -3, 160, 40))
        textHeader.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        textHeader.text = self.menus[indexPath.row]
        textHeader.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        textHeader.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 16)
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(textHeader)

        let textDetail = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(45, 13, 160, 40))
        textDetail.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        textDetail.text = self.detailmenus[indexPath.row]
        textDetail.textColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 198/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        textDetail.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12)
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(textDetail)

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 25, 25))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: thumbils[indexPath.row])
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    return cell!
}
```

I've tried to change text detail label like this but it did not worked

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var colorSelected = UIColor(red: 3/255, green: 134/255, blue: 27/255, alpha: 1)
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = colorSelected 
}
```

What should I do to change detailTextLabel color?

Comment: I dont see that you have detailTextLabel in your cell? Did you create it? You are not using subclass or anything

Comment: @IxPaka i create detailTextLabel with Label textDetail because i've 'something' conditions, but how can i change my label in didSelectRowAtIndexPath if row have selected...

Comment: your textDetail label, is not detailTextLabel, thats why you cant change its color, textDetail label is a label which you added on your cell but dont have any reference to it

Answer (score 1):

You should create your cell in interface builder, its a bad idea to create every component in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in fact this is what you should do.

Subclass UITableViewCell, use it in interface builder, create outlet for that label, use this cell in interface builder, drop label on it, connect your outlet to that label and now you have access to that label. Now you dont have to create that label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because you did it in interface builder.

Next step is pretty simple and you have it pretty much correctly, but your detailTextLabel is not set.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var colorSelected = UIColor(red: 3/255, green: 134/255, blue: 27/255, alpha: 1)
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.detailTextLabel?.textColor = colorSelected 
}
```

Check out this tutorial on tableview: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout skip to part "create a basic custom cell" and you should get how to do it